# SQL Server - Select Query - Inner Join - Error message: Cannot resolve the collation conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, inner-join

I'm performing this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT *
FROM [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados]
INNER JOIN [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO] ON [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados].[NumeroReloj] = [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO].[Badgenumber]
```

As you can see, there are 2 databases, 2 tables, and 2 different columns.

In table `CAT_Empleados`, I have all the employees (around 3,000) - here the employee# column is `NumeroReloj`.

And in table `USERINFO`, I have around 250 employees - here the employee# column is `Badgenumber`.

What I'm trying to find is all employees who are in `USERINFO` and are not in `CAT_EMPLEADOS` (by the Employee#).

But I'm getting this error when I run the query:

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 4
>   Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Chinese_PRC_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Looks like a unicode issue. 

Do you have any Chinese or non-English lettering in your CAT_Empleados?

Comment: You need to use the keyword [`COLLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017#examples) on (at least) one of the columns in your join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can always use `COLLATE` at the end of your `SELECT` statement

```
[PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados].[NumeroReloj] = [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO].[Badgenumber] COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS   (OR THE OTHER ONE)
```

Comment: Hi. It works!
'''
COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS
'''
Thank you!

Now I have another Question...
How to delete All Employees that I found with this query in [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO]
But I'm going to close this question and make another one.
Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `collate database_default` to resolve the conflict.

so your code will be like this

```
SELECT *
FROM [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados]
INNER JOIN [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO]
ON [PBS].[dbo].[CAT_Empleados].[NumeroReloj] = [AccessControl].[dbo].[USERINFO].[Badgenumber] collate database_default
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I fix it by:
'''
COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AS
'''
Thank you!